# How do I train a model using two loss functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow graph with two loss functions. I want to train my model alternatively:

1. Train the model using the first loss function.
2. Train the model using the second loss function.
3. Repeat one and two until convergence.

Do I have to create two graphs then load, train and save the weights for every step? Or Is it possible to achieve that with a single graph?

Comment: I think it may be useful to state why you want to achieve such a thing: why using two loss functions?

Comment: I m working on deep clustering and I m trying different ideas for a research project. Generally, we need a clustering and a reconstruction loss functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=42.)
y = tf.square(x)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)

train_min = optimizer.minimize(y)  # minimize x*x
train_max = optimizer.minimize(-y) # maximize x*x

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for _ in range(20):
        cost, _ = sess.run([y, train_min])
        print(cost)
        cost, _ = sess.run([y, train_max])
        print(cost)
```

If you don't mind to minimize both cost function on *exactly* the same batch, you can even write

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=42.)
y = tf.square(x)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)

train_min = optimizer.minimize(y)

with tf.control_dependencies([train_min]):
    train_min_then_max = optimizer.minimize(-y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for _ in range(20):
        cost, _ = sess.run([y, train_min_then_max])
        print(cost)
```

which does the optimization with a single sess.run call.